# Android Serial Usb Port

Tags: android, usb, serial-port

I wana to develop an application that read data  coming from serial port devices like gps etc.
I had pl2303 serial to usb cable and the tab i am using for this purpose has the specs..

Ainol Novo 7 Advanced ii
Model Number : GTI900
Android Version : 4.0.3
Baseband 0.3
Android Kernel : 3.0.8

As the tab lack pl2303.ko my questions are from where should I get the mentioned kernel also how to install pl2303.ko in the kernel.

Regards

Comment: still waiting for any responce..........

Comment: the issue is solved know by flashing custom rom.........

Answer (score 0):

**Should Work, No Rooting Required**
*This is an older thread, but it turns up high in search results...*
I thought I'd let people know that as of the stock Android ICS 4.0.3, (*and possibly backfilled into earlier versions, I've seen reports that as long as your device supports USB Host mode ie. since Honeycomb 3.1*), that Prolific PL2303 (as well as FTDI) chip support should be built in.
I know mine just *works* on my Toshiba Thrive, no rooting, not fancy stuff. Although I consider that the Thrive is one of the few mass-market tabblies with a full size USB (A) host port, so I think they may have made sure it was working.
Other devices, particularly cellphones, may have had the serial I/O modules stripped out to fit a smaller (cheaper) ROM, even though they have a micro-USB port.